# PHPMailer "Could Not Access File:"

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer, email-attachments

I am trying to email a file that exists on my server using PHPMailer. When I run this code, I get "Could not access file" and the email sends without the attachment... what is wrong here??

```
<html>
<title>Email Sent!</title>
<?php 
        include("menu.php");
        include("sqlconnect.php");
        require_once('../PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');

        $path = $_POST['path'];
        $filename = $_POST['filename'];
        $newpath = "Library/WebServer/Documents/Inventory/".$path;

define('GUSER', 'xxxxxxx@gmail.com'); // GMail username
define('GPWD', 'xxxxxxx'); // GMail password


function smtpmailer($to, $from, $from_name, $subject, $body) { 
    global $error;
    $mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 465; 
    $mail->Username = GUSER;  
    $mail->Password = GPWD;           
    $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    $attachtest = $mail->AddAttachment($newpath);   
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
        return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Message sent!';
        return true;
    }
}

smtpmailer('xxxxxxx@me.com', 'xxxxxxxx@gmail.com', 'Name', 'test mail message', 'Hello World!');

?>
</html>
```

Comment: As far as I can tell you are never using your `$filename` variable. Is that intended? Also you don't pass `$newpath` into your function as a parameter.

Comment: @Dan Well, when I use AddAttachment, you can specify a filename to rename the file after it is attached. I'm not using it at the moment because I need functionality first. And should I pass it's as a parameter?

Comment: I don't see any other place in your script where the file could be read from the file system. Is there code missing? What part of the code throws that error message?

Comment: @Dan I'm not sure, I think it is the AddAttachment line, because I've commented everything else out and when it hits that line, it produces an error.

Comment: Try `echo $newpath;` right before that line. AddAttachment is probably trying to attach your file but you pass it an empty string.

Comment: @Dan when I echo before the function, it prints the path on the page. But if I echo inside the function just before AddAttachment, nothing is echoed/printed.

Comment: As I said. You don't pass `$newpath` into your function. Thus it is an empty string.

Comment: @Dan `function smtpmailer($to, $from, $from_name, $subject, $body, $newpath)`?

Comment: Exactly. I added an answer with the code for you.

Comment: @Dan It worked!! I used $path instead of $newpath when I called the function though. Works perfect now! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the correct path into your function like this

```
function smtpmailer($to, $from, $from_name, $subject, $body, $newpath)
```

and calling it like

```
 smtpmailer('xxxxxxx@me.com', 'xxxxxxxx@gmail.com', 'Name', 'test mail message', 'Hello World!', $newpath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user/group that Apache and PHP are running under have at least READ permissions on the file.

This issue is common if you're working on a server and upload files using sFTP/SSH as a different user.

Find out what user and group apache/php are running under and give that user and group read access to the file you are trying to attache.

Comment: @sanjanNOPPIX I gave all of the files and folders on my server read and write access to everyone. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.

I needed to run an extra command into my php script that move_uploaded_file() to an internal directory from my host home, then so now I could send the attachment.

That my tip that works well for me :)