# could not access file error in phpmailer function

Tags: php, email

I have written this code to send mail through an HTML form using php mailer, but after clicking on the submit button, it shows me this error "Could Not Access File". I have tried almost everything but it doesnt seem to be working.
If anyone can help me out here that would be great.

FORM Code :

```
 <form name="contactform" role="form" name="contactForm" action="send_form_careers.php" method="post" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <label for="name">Full Name</label><br>
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="text" required><br><br>
                        <label for="phone">Phone</label><br>
                        <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" class="text" required><br><br>
                        <label for="email">Email</label><br>
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="text" required><br><br>          
                        <input type="file" name="my_file" id="my_file" class="inputfile" required />
                        <label for="file">Upload Your Resume</label>
                        <div class="button" style="text-align:center">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-read" value="Submit" name="submit">
                        </div>
                   </div>
                   </form>
```

php file

```
<?php 
include('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

try {
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); //New instance, with exceptions enabled

$to = "giteshnnd@gmail.com";
$mail->AddAddress($to);
$mail->From       = $_POST['email'];
$mail->FromName   = $_POST['name'];
$mail->Subject  = "Test Email using PHP";

$body             = "<table>
                         <tr>
                            <th colspan='2'>This Sample Mail</th>
                         </tr>

                         <tr>
                            <td style='font-weight:bold'>Name :</td>
                            <td>".$_POST['name']."</td>
                         </tr>

                         <tr>
                          <td style='font-weight:bold'>E-mail : </td>
                          <td>".$_POST['email']."</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                          <td style='font-weight:bold'>Phone : </td>
                          <td>".$_POST['phone']."</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                          <td style='font-weight:bold'>Message : </td>
                          <td>".$_POST['message']."</td>
                        </tr>
                     <table>";
$body             = preg_replace('/\\\\/','', $body); //Strip backslashes
$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->IsSMTP();                           // tell the class to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Port       = 25;                    // set the SMTP server port
//$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // SMTP server
//$mail->Username   = "name@domain.com";     // SMTP server username
//$mail->Password   = "password";            // SMTP server password

$mail->IsSendmail();  // tell the class to use Sendmail
$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
$mail->WordWrap   = 80; // set word wrap

$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
                     $_FILES['file']['name']);
$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML
$mail->Send();
echo 'Message has been sent.';
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
echo $e->errorMessage();

}

?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [“Could Not Access File:” in PHPmail function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21216883/could-not-access-file-in-phpmail-function)

Comment: I dont understand, how can that be fixed?

Comment: check your file path

Comment: file path is correct.

Comment: check your file path first.

        1. your form action is `action="send_form_careers.php"`
        2. so your `send_form_careers.php` will be same folder with your form file
        3. send_form_careers.php file you `include('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');` so your send_form_careers.php and this file structure will be phpmailer/
        4. check your file permission that 644

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280485/phpmailer-could-not-access-file

Comment: yes...ll these files are in the correct folder

Answer (score 0):

Your input file named "my_file". Look:

But you addressed `$_FILES` from named index "file":

```
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
                     $_FILES['file']['name']);
```

Correct code:

```
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name'],
                     $_FILES['my_file']['name']);
```